# Odoo: How to message_post() after 'adding a new line' to a form

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I would like to post a message on the chatterbox after I add a new line in my model. I tried putting the `tracking=True` attribute on the one2many field (that represents my line model) in my main model, but nothing was logged on the chatterbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
model_id = self.env['your.model'].search([('id', '=', 255)])
msg_body = "First Log Note"
model_id.message_post(body=msg_body)

...

msg_body = "Second Log Note"
model_id.message_post(body=msg_body)
```

Make sure you inherit this mixin ( **_inherit = ['mail.thread']** )in your model.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'your.model'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put it in def create or write function then add this to your code.

Ex. in write function (whenever you edit your one2many field.)

```
@api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
         if 'one2many_fields' in vals:
             self.message_post(
                 body="Test",
                 message_type='comment',
                 subtype='mail.mt_comment'
         )
         return super(YourClassName, self).write(vals)
```

when you save the record and there's changes in your one2many field, the "Test" message will display in the chatter.

I hope it will help you.